# Can't build PCL using xbuild on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mono, xamarin

I made a PCL in Xamarin Studio. I want to provide an automatic build process on my CI server. I read that i should be using xbuild. So, on my ubuntu 12.04 server (where the building will be going on) i did the following:

> sudo apt-get install mono-xbuild

Then i cloned my repository and did the following command:

> xbuild Project.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:Build

TIt is referencing this Library in my build script:

> Project.csproj: error : /home/user/project/Project.csproj: /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/Portable/v4.5/Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets: Project file could not be imported, it was being imported by /home/user/project/Project.csproj: Imported project: "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/Portable/v4.5/Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" does not exist.

When i go to /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft i only see the following:

`Silverlight/  VisualStudio/`

So the `Portable/` folder isn't present.

Is it possible to reference it or to obtain it somehow? What steps need to be done to get this build to pass? Am i missing crucial steps? Im kind of new to this building via command-line thing.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: It is written in the latest version of Xamarin. It is a portable class library and i don't which version of mono it is.

Comment: then ask in xamarin forums